# ¿Como hacer un responsive utilizando Porcentajes?

Tags: html, css

Busco hacer un responsive de forma escalar usando porcentajes ejemplo: ( 33.3% , 50% 65% 100% ). para ir degradando el ancho de la pantalla

```css
.container{
  align-items: center;
}
.cajas{
  float: left;
 background: brown;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100px;
  color: white;
  margin: 3px;
}
```

```html
<body>
 <div class="Container">
  <div class="cajas"> 1 </div>
  <div class="cajas"> 2 </div> 
  <div class="cajas"> 3 </div>
  <div class="cajas"> 4 </div>  
 </div>
</body>
```

Comment: me puede ser util pero ahorita busco es usar es media query; utilizando porcentaje

Comment: No entiendo a que queires llegar. Explica mejor

Comment: quiero hacer un responsive que se valla adaptando a la pantalla y no quiero ser 3 escalas como 320px-720px-1280px; sino lo que quiero es aplicar meda query asi : 33.3%-50%-57%-65%-76%-90%-100%. Aplicarlo con porcentajes no se si me entienden ??.

Comment: Puedes usar https://getbootstrap.com/ para usar las grillas con porcentajes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algo asi es que ocupas?

```css
.container{
  align-items: center;
}
.cajas{
  float: left;
 background: brown;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100px;
  color: white;
  margin: 3px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 400px) {
    .cajas {width: 25%; }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    .cajas {width: 50%; }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
    .cajas {width: 100%; }
}
```

```html
<body>
 <div class="Container">
  <div class="cajas"> 1 </div>
  <div class="cajas"> 2 </div> 
  <div class="cajas"> 3 </div>
  <div class="cajas"> 4 </div>  
 </div>
</body>
```

Comment: oye dejame hacer pruebas porque estoy un poco distorcionado de como es exactamente como trabaja lo que ando buscando. por cierto porque el float o flex no funcionan ?. corrigeme en caso que lo redacte mal

Comment: Si funciona, puedes hacer pruebas con float:right y veras como cambia. Y flex es una nueva propiedad css3 que actua de forma parecida al float. Puedes probar con display: flex y veras como cambia

Comment: hare varias pruebas antes de continuar con el problema

Comment: perfecto amigo esta bien; aunque pienso que hay otra forma que es la que ando buscando pero aun no lo tengo claro, seguire buscando

Comment: Tambien puedes poner varias concdiciones, algo asi: `@media screen and (max-width: 995px) , screen and (max-height: 700px) {
  ...
}` Ademas puedes ver [esto](https://css-tricks.com/logic-in-media-queries/)

Comment: Lo que hando buscando es algo asi : .col-1 {width: 8.33%;}
.col-2 {width: 16.66%;}
.col-3 {width: 25%;}
.col-4 {width: 33.33%;}
.col-5 {width: 41.66%;}
.col-6 {width: 50%;}
.col-7 {width: 58.33%;}
.col-8 {width: 66.66%;}
.col-9 {width: 75%;}
.col-10 {width: 83.33%;}
.col-11 {width: 91.66%;}
.col-12 {width: 100%;}

Comment: es un uso de cuadrilla estoy buscando informacion sobre esta para aplicarlo o usarlo con media query

Answer (score 1):

No se si te he entendido bien, ya que lo interpreto de dos maneras:

**1) Quieres usar media queries con porcentajes, algo así:**

```
@media (min-width: 8.33%){
/*Estilos*/
}

@media (min-width: 16.66%){
/*Estilos*/
}
```

Si es lo que buscas, de una vez te doy un spoiler: **esto no se puede hacer**, ya que los media sólo se definen con medidas absolutas (px, em, cm, rem) y no con relativas (%, vmin, vh, vw).

**2) Ahora si buscas es una especie de twitter bootstrap donde tú defines personalizadamente los porcentajes de las columnas**, pues en realidad el mismo bootstrap te sirve, pero la otra opción es usar variables css y definir tu mismo un bootstrap, te doy un ejemplo:

```
:root{
  /*Este es el numero de la columna, por defecto puede ser 1*/
  --n-columna: 1;
  /*Defines el numero de grillas que hay en cada movil*/
  --grid-xs: 4;
  --grid-s: 6;
  --grid-m: 10;
  --grid-l: 12;      
  --ancho-movil: calc( (100% / var(--grid-xs) ) * var(--n-columna) ); 
  --ancho-tableta: calc( (100% / var(--grid-s) ) * var(--n-columna) ); 
  --ancho-laptop: calc( (100% / var(--grid-m) ) * var(--n-columna) ); 
  --ancho-monitor: calc( (100% / var(--grid-l) ) * var(--n-columna) );
}

.col-1{
  --n-columna: 1;
  /*La ultima formula de arriba se transformara en monitores así:
  * calc( (100% / 12) * 1) que es aproximadamente: 8.33%
  */ 
}

.col-2{
  --n-columna: 2;
  /*En este caso la formula de arriba se transformara en:
  * monitores grandes:
  * calc( (100% / 12) * 2) que es aproximadamente: 16.66%
  * en laptops:
  * calc( (100% / 10) * 2) que es aproximadamente: 20%
  * en tablets:
  * calc( (100% / 6) * 2) que es aproximadamente: 33.33%
  * en celulares:
  * calc( (100% / 4) * 2) que es aproximadamente: 50%
  */ 
}

.col-3{
  --n-columna: 3;
  /*Y así sucesivamente con cada columna.*/ 
}

.col-4{ --n-columna: 4; }
.col-5{ --n-columna: 5; }
.col-6{ --n-columna: 6; }
.col-7{ --n-columna: 7; }
.col-8{ --n-columna: 8; }
.col-9{ --n-columna: 9; }
.col-10{ --n-columna: 10; }
.col-11{ --n-columna: 11; }
.col-12{ --n-columna: 12; }

/*En cuanto a los queries quedarían como te muestro a continuación
* y no tienes que tocarlos más, ya que solo debes modificar
* La variables definidas en el root*/

@media (min-width: 620px){ /*o la medida que definas para moviles*/
  .col-1, .col-2, .col-3, .col-4,
  .col-5, .col-6, .col-7, .col-8
  .col-9, .col-10, .col-11, .col-12 
  { width: var(--ancho-movil) }
}

@media (min-width: 860px){ /*o la medida que definas para tablets*/
  .col-1, .col-2, .col-3, .col-4,
  .col-5, .col-6, .col-7, .col-8
  .col-9, .col-10, .col-11, .col-12
  { width: var(--ancho-laptop) }
}

@media (min-width: 1240px){ /*o la medida que definas para laptops*/
  .col-1, .col-2, .col-3, .col-4,
  .col-5, .col-6, .col-7, .col-8
  .col-9, .col-10, .col-11, .col-12
  { width: var(--ancho-laptop) }
}

@media (min-width: 1920px){ /*o la medida que definas para monitores más grandes*/
  .col-1, .col-2, .col-3, .col-4,
  .col-5, .col-6, .col-7, .col-8
  .col-9, .col-10, .col-11, .col-12
  { width: var(--ancho-monitor) }
}
```

Comment: que usas tu para asignar variables en el css ?, sass ???

Comment: Nada, esas son variables nativas de css3. Ahora también puedes hacer lo mismo con variables de SASS sin problema.

Comment: Puedes leer más sobre estas aquí: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/var y https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables.